# Howto add two scripts in the head section of the site descriptor file of maven-site-plugin?

Tags: maven, maven-site-plugin

I have a pom module where I define a site file descriptor:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="${project.name}" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.4.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.4.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/decoration-1.4.0.xsd">
  <body>
    <head>
      <script type="text/javascript" src="http://common.nuiton.org/dev/js/pom-site.js">

      </script>
    </head>
  </body>
</project>
```

Now I have a child maven module of the first module with this site descriptor:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="${project.name}" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.4.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/DECORATION/1.4.0   http://maven.apache.org/xsd/decoration-1.4.0.xsd">
  <body>
    <head>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#mavenProjectProperties).attr('scmwebeditor_vmFiles', ',install,update,usage,configure,');
      }
      </script>
    </head>
  </body>
</project>
```

when generating the child site, I got a strange html code:

```
<script id="myscript" src="http://common.nuiton.org/dev/js/pom-site.js" type="text/javascript">$(document).ready(function () {
      $('#mavenProjectProperties).attr('scmwebeditor_vmFiles', ',install,update,usage,configure,');
    }</script>
```

How can I make this working ? I will probably open an issue